# MAX usage for each day for each group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, max

Every hour I upload data HOURLY for 6 different groups(DG). How do I get the maximum value (usage) for each group for each day? I can't seem to get it to group by the date.

Example Data (2 hours of upload shown but there would be 24 for each day)

```
DG         Usage       UploadDateTime
 ---------  ---------  ----------
 1          100         2012-08-30 10:00:03.000
 2          500         2012-08-30 10:00:03.000
 3          400         2012-08-30 10:00:03.000
 4          550         2012-08-30 10:00:03.000
 5          220         2012-08-30 10:00:03.000
 6          110         2012-08-30 10:00:03.000
 1          200         2012-08-30 11:00:03.000
 2          600         2012-08-30 11:00:03.000
 3          450         2012-08-30 11:00:03.000
 4          200         2012-08-30 11:00:03.000
 5          240         2012-08-30 11:00:03.000
 6          50          2012-08-30 11:00:03.000
```

Intended output: (This is only a single day, would want a block for each day of available data)

```
DG         Usage       UploadDateTime
 ---------  ---------  ----------
 1          200         2012-08-30 11:00:03.000
 2          600         2012-08-30 11:00:03.000
 3          450         2012-08-30 11:00:03.000
 4          550         2012-08-30 10:00:03.000
 5          240         2012-08-30 11:00:03.000
 6          110         2012-08-30 10:00:03.000
```

EDIT ** I updated the fields to not reflect reserved words.

Comment: *"How do I get the maximum value (usage) for each group for each day?"* What's wrong with `MAX`?

Comment: When I use Max(Usage) and group by Group, DateTime it returns usage for each hour not day. I'm fairly new to T-SQL and probably missing something simple.

Comment: You need to `CAST`/`CONVERT` the value of `datetime` to a `date`

Comment: It would be helpful to indicate if any of the answers helped you resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will need to convert your `date` column to date only using `CONVERT(date, [UploadDateTime])`. I assume your actual column has a name that is not `datetime` and that you want the `SUM` for each group for each day which is what you sample results show.

Then with `SUM` and `GROUP BY` you can do something like:

```
SELECT
    DG,
    SUM(Usage) AS [UseForDay],
    CONVERT(date, [UploadDateTime]) AS [UploadDateTime]
FROM
    MyTable
GROUP BY
    DG,    
    CONVERT(date, [UploadDateTime])
```

Comment: `GROUP` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: Sorry for my poor choice of example. The 'group' is not actually called group. I'll update the initial post to make it less confusing. I originally tried this as well but in the group by clause the 'As' is hilighted in the 'CONVERT(date, [myDateTime]) AS [Date]' statement

Answer (score 0):

If you want the time after date as you have in the "intended output" you can use row number:

```
SELECT [group],
       usage,
       [datetime]
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [group], CAST([datetime] AS DATE) ORDER BY usage DESC) AS Row_Num
    FROM #Usage
) UsageRow
WHERE Row_Num = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is what you want (I've added in a little bit of data for another date)

```
use tempdb
GO
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DATA
CREATE TABLE #DATA (
    DG INTEGER
    , Usage INTEGER
    , UploadDateTime DATETIME2(3)
)

INSERT INTO #DATA (
    DG, Usage, UploadDateTime
)
SELECT 1,          100,         '2012-08-30 10:00:03.000' UNION ALL
SELECT  2,          500,         '2012-08-30 10:00:03.000' UNION ALL
SELECT  3,          400,         '2012-08-30 10:00:03.000' UNION ALL
SELECT  4,          550,         '2012-08-30 10:00:03.000' UNION ALL
SELECT  5,          220,         '2012-08-30 10:00:03.000' UNION ALL
SELECT  6,          110,         '2012-08-30 10:00:03.000' UNION ALL
SELECT  1,          200,         '2012-08-30 11:00:03.000' UNION ALL
SELECT  2,          600,         '2012-08-30 11:00:03.000' UNION ALL
SELECT  3,          450,         '2012-08-30 11:00:03.000' UNION ALL
SELECT  4,          200,         '2012-08-30 11:00:03.000' UNION ALL
SELECT  5,          240,         '2012-08-30 11:00:03.000' UNION ALL
SELECT  6,          50 ,         '2012-08-30 11:00:03.000' UNION ALL
SELECT  6,          51 ,         '2012-08-31 10:00:03.000' UNION ALL
SELECT  6,          52 ,         '2012-08-31 11:00:03.000' 

SELECT * FROM #DATA

-- what is the max usage for each DG by date
SELECT DG, CAST(UploadDateTime AS DATE) AS UploadDate, MAX(Usage)
FROM #DATA
GROUP BY DG, CAST(UploadDateTime AS DATE)

-- using the max usage for each DG by date to join back to the orginal data
-- to get the datetime that relates to the max value
; WITH MAXES AS (
    SELECT DG, CAST(UploadDateTime AS DATE) AS UploadDate, MAX(Usage) AS MaxUsage
    FROM #DATA
    GROUP BY DG, CAST(UploadDateTime AS DATE)
)
SELECT #DATA.*
FROM #DATA
INNER JOIN MAXES    
    ON #DATA.DG = MAXES.DG
    AND CAST(#DATA.UploadDateTime AS DATE) = MAXES.UploadDate
    AND #DATA.Usage = MaxUsage
ORDER BY UploadDate ASC, DG ASC
```